# collections and jax-rs

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

Let's say I have a collection, /cars, which supports the usual operations, and I also have support for /cars/{id}.

What is the best-practice for returning only a limited "view" of the collection elements when I get a GET for /cars?
Namely, it'd be enough to list maybe id, name, and the client needs further info, he can query it more detail via /cars/{id}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good candidate for Jackon's `@JsonView` annotation. I usually define some marker interfaces in a common package (can be reused across an app):

```
public interface View {
    public interface Partial { }
    public interface Full extends Partial { }
}
```

And then you can use them in the car class like so:

```
public class Car {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //Supresses serialization of this property when another view is active
    @JsonView(View.Full.class)
    private String description;

    ......
}
```

and finally activate the appropriate view in your resource:

```
@Path("/")
@JsonView(View.Partial.class)
public Collection<Car> getAll();

@Path("/{id}")
@JsonView(View.Full.class)
public Car getById(@PathParam("id") int id);
```

A word of caution, ommiting `@JsonView(View.Partial.class)` from the `getAll()` method will cause ALL properties to be serialized (in this case one might expect `description` to not be serialized). This is because Jackson disables view processing and ignores all view annotations unless there is an explicit view specified for rendering. I wrote a workaround for this (so that when no view is specified, only properties belonging to the default view are serialized). I could only get it working for serialization but not deserialization, if you're interested I can try to dig it up.

Comment: Ok, I just gave this a try with IBM's WebSphere Liberty Profile and sadly couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Did you have a problem defining and using the views or did it just not have the desired effect at runtime?

Comment: Liberty 8.5.0.x ignores the JsonView annotation on the resource method, so ObjectMapper doesn't know about which view to use. I'll talk to the guys to support it in a later version.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any experience with Liberty. It's actually the `JacksonJsonProvider` that should be picking up on the annotation, are you able to register this provider with Liberty and let it handle JSON reading/writing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use some ORM library in the backend, define two distinct classes: one mapping all details of that entity, the other only a few of its attributes that are relevant for an overview. Then simply return these to different types in your two methods.

I think it's a pretty much standard pattern, at least I've came across this technique in projects I've been working on.

Comment: Of course this works, but it feels very hackish and results in code-duplication. I'm really hoping there is a nicer solution...

Comment: It does result in some code duplication, but a class with a few properties and the corresponding mapping metadata is rather lightweight. Applying some clever filtering interceptor/aspect/whatever may seem to be cool at the first sight, but _that is_ a hack which makes your code a lot less understandable and maintainable. A simple solution that immediately reflects your intention when reading the code is always better, in my opinion.

Comment: How would you use this approach from the codebase? Let's say you have a List<Car> ready; would you then create a SimpleCar with just the desired resources, and wrap every Car into this SimpleCar? That means at every return I have to call a "transformer" method, with clutters the code.

Comment: If your API is consequent in this regard, and always returns SimpleCars when the client requests a collection, then you should have a repository that is able to load List<SimpleCar>. If it's not the case then you are probably right, and will need some hack around the serialization process to filter the entity's attributes.